# Own user control with new property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I want to create a control like this:

[image: Control]

I created view and viewmodel of this control and I added new property - "FileURL".

I want to use this property like this:

```
<vm:FileSelector FileURL="{Binding Something}"/>
```

And now it is a problem:

My new control contains button and textbox.
I want that property "FileURL" of FileSelector contains the same value as "Text" of TextBox used inside FileSelector.

So in XAML declaration of new control i wanted to add something like that:

```
<UserControl x:Class="namespace.FileSelector"
...
FileURL="{Binding ElementName=txtBoxExampleName, Path=Text}">
```

But this operation is not allowed.

I do not know how can i change value of property "FileURL" inside FileSelector control using MVVM pattern.

Comment: If you want to bind to the Something property (in a view model) in different controls that is easy. Too easy, so guessing you have more going on here. Suggest you lay out enough of your ViewModel code to see how it relates to the view and then get some better answers. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that FileURL is a `DependencyProperty` in FileSelector then you would just do the following in the FileSelector.xaml:

```
     <TextBox Text="{Binding FileURL, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have another DataContext (with button logic, commands, etc) so I can't set DataContext to self.

Comment: I've updated to point the Binding `RelativeSource` instead of setting the `DataContext` on the `UserControl`

Comment: Ok, but in your example FileSelector is name of property to binding? I could be wrong but It should be like that:
Text="{Binding FileURL, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:FileSelector}}}" ?

Both versions do not work.

Comment: Yes the binding path should be FileURL, my mistake. But the AncestorType should be UserControl assuming that FileSelector is a UserControl. I have tested it and it is working for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.
It almost works, but...
When I did like that:
<vm:FileSelector FileURL="test" />
It's works!
But I want to do like that:
<vm:FileSelector FileURL="{Binding something}" />
And this code doesn't work...
I checked if that is a problem with DataContext etc, I created TextBox with the same binding:
<TextBox Text="{Binding something}" />
And It works... But why binding to my dependency property does not work?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you but I created a UserControl and bound the FileURL DependencyProperty like so `<TestUserControl FileUrl="{Binding TestText}"/>` and it works. There must be something else going on in your code. Have you tried using Snoop? It shows any data context errors if there are any.

Comment: Thanks for answer and help. I forgot delete my comment. Problem was solved, It was my stupid mistake. Your code is good. :)